# помогите написать алгоритм бинарного поиска со сложностью O(log2n)

Tags: java, binary

Условия следующие:
Есть массив со значениями: например [14, 16, 19, 32, 32, 32, 56, 69, 72].- размеры книг....

Нужно написать функцию, которая бы принимала этот массив, размер новой книги и возвращала бы количество больших по размеру книг по алгоритму бинарного поиска. **НО Вызывать готовые реализации бинарного поиска запрещено.**

Например если вызвать функция со значением 32, то должно вернуть 3, если со значением 60 то 2!(т.к. только две книги на полке строго больше чем 60 страницы). и.т.д.
**При этом продолжать поиск нужно именно бинарным поиском, нельзя просто взять и пройтись вправо по равным элементам до тех пор пока не встретим больший....**
написал код

```
public class Main {
     public static int binarySearch(int[]arr, int x){
         int left = 0;
         int right = arr.length-1;
         while(left <= right) {
             int middleIndex = (left + right) / 2;
             // если средний элемент - целевой элемент, вернуть его индекс
             if (arr[middleIndex] == x) {

                 return (arr.length-1) - middleIndex;
             }

             // если средний элемент меньше
             // направляем наш индекс в middle+1, убирая первую часть из рассмотрения
             else if (arr[middleIndex] < x)
                 left = middleIndex + 1;

                 // если средний элемент больше
                 // направляем наш индекс в middle-1, убирая вторую часть из рассмотрения
             else if (arr[middleIndex] > x)
                 right = middleIndex - 1;

         }
         return -1;
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        int[]array = new int[]{12,13,14,15};
     int result =  Main.binarySearch(array,14);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
```

А если в массиве  int[]array = new int[]{12,13,14,14,14,15}; вот так например?

Вот моё решение:

```
    public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int x) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = arr.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        int middleIndex = (left + right) / 2;
        // если средний элемент - целевой элемент, вернуть его индекс
        if (arr[middleIndex] <= x && arr[middleIndex] < arr[middleIndex + 1]) {
            return (arr.length - 1) - middleIndex;
        } else if (arr[middleIndex] <= x && arr[middleIndex] == arr[middleIndex + 1]) {
            left = middleIndex + 1;
        }

        // если средний элемент меньше
        // направляем наш индекс в middle+1, убирая первую часть из рассмотрения
        else if (arr[middleIndex] < x)
            left = middleIndex + 1;

            // если средний элемент больше
            // направляем наш индекс в middle-1, убирая вторую часть из рассмотрения
        else if (arr[middleIndex] > x)
            right = middleIndex - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: В интернете не пробовали найти? Куча примеров и реализаций получите, просто загуглив.

Comment: Даже по названию метода "бинарный (двоичный) поиск" можно самому заново его изобрести. Делите отрезок пополам, смотрите, какой элемент получился в середине...

Comment: да обычный алгоритм то я легко написал сам, вопрос в  условии когда книг в массиве больше одной с одинаковыми страницами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вам нужно при `int[]array = new int[]{12,13,14,14,14,15};` и `x = 14`, функция возвращала 1.

Тогда вам нужна функция, которая называется `upper_bound`, она возвращает индекс элемента, который строго > переданного в неё.

```
public static int upper_bound(int arr[], int x) { 
    int mid;
    int low = 0; 
    int high = arr.length; 

    while (low < high) {
        mid = low + (high - low) / 2; 

        if (x >= arr[mid]) 
            low = mid + 1;
        else 
            high = mid; 
    }
    return low; 
}
```

Теперь вы можете вызвать функцию `upperd_bound` передав в неё массив `array` и элемент `x = 14`. Если такого элемента не найдено, то будет возвращен размер переданного массива.

Далее от размера массива вы отнимаете результат функции и получаете кол-во книг.

Например в вашем примере будет возвращен индекс `5`. Следовательно `6 - 5 = 1` - кол-во книг. Если `x = 13`, то будет возвращен индекс `2`. Следовательно `6 - 2 = 4` - кол-во книг.

[Сайт](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-upper_bound-and-lower_bound-in-c/) где рассказывается об этих функциях (только там на си код, но разница не большая)

Comment: @YuraKopshev так вы тоже отнимаете) на строчке `return (arr.length-1) - middleIndex;`, просто у вас это занесено в функцию. Можете просто `return arr.length - low` в моей функции написать и все. А так же переименовать `upper_bound` на `binarySearch`.

Comment: Спасибо Павел Вам!

Comment: @YuraKopshev если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста отметьте его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)